# InfoPath 2007 Web-based form to show different page views

Tags: infopath, form, page-view, forms-services

I have created a web-based InfoPath form that have 4 views (a.k.a Page Views) - View All, Loan View, Price View and Location View.

May I know what buttons or settings I have to click or configure in order to be able to select which views that I want to see when I am filling up the web-based InfoPath form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Advanced Form Settings, Web Browser Category, you need to check (or tick) the checkbox for the Views. Hope it help.

Comment: By the way, just to inform you that a message 'The data on this form might have changed. Are you sure you want to close this form?' will pop-up if you close the form after changing the page view only (without any changes to the data in any of the fields in the form). Not sure if this is a bug or probably I did not set some settings else where. Maybe you can let us know if you also encounter such scenario too.

Comment: Yes, I do got the message if I close the form but with a different page view only but still +1 for your answer.